# "Custody of exams"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, translation

I'm trying to translate a sentence and I don't know if I am correct. I am trying to say that professors keep the exams with student's answers in a box under lock and key for several months because the law says so, to prevent losing them, and it's for a form to fill out to make a request.

- Request **custody of exams** ?
- Request **exam custody** ?
- Request ***safekeeping* of exams** ?

For Spanish speakers, my sentence is "Solicitud custodia de exámenes".

Comment: There are several interpretations of your question. Please [edit] it to clarify. Are you asking about the exam questions (paper) before the exam is taken, or after it is taken? Or are you asking about the papers with the students' answers? Or, all of these variations?

Comment: Are you using this in a sentence, or is it more like a title of a form to fill out to make the request?

Comment: It is a title of a form to make a request.

Comment: In the financial world, regulations require that documents be [retained](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/retain) for a certain period in case they might be needed later, so that might be a good place to start. I will have to think about it a little more before I can write a proper answer.

Comment: "Request for Secure Retention of Exam Results " might be the way I would title the form if I were trying to be very official. It's pretty verbose though. Maybe someone will think of something more concise.

Comment: I would understand "exam results" to mean just the scores or marks, @ColleenV, not the answer papers.

Comment: @ColinFine Yep, which is why it's a comment and not a real answer. "scored exams" is an alternative. I don't like answer papers, especially when you can get a degree entirely on-line, but that may be an AmE bias. My assumption is that anyone who is filling out the form is going to understand why they're filling it out and is unlikely to confuse it with a request to archive the unanswered exam questions or just the numbers, especially since there is law involved. Unless there is another law that says that the exam questions should be retained by a separate request. Context is everything :)

Comment: @ColleenV: for an online exam, I think I'd use something like "exam submissions" or "submitted answers".

Comment: @ColinFine But we don't know whether this is for all types of answered exams or not, and it's just a title so we would want to choose the most generic term. It's odd that I can't think of a term for "answers someone gave on an exam" without confusing it with the answer key, or the score they got. Or maybe I'm just over-thinking it and "exams" would get the point across just fine even though it's not really precise. When someone looks at the form and sees "Name of Student whose answers should be retained:" it doesn't really matter that the title said "exams" I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand "exam" in the sense of "student's completed answer paper" in English. (It might work in context, if you had already established that you were talking about these, and then used "exams" as a shorthand; but not otherwise).

I'm not sure there is an established term for these. Some possibilities that occur to me are:

> completed exams
>
> answer papers
>
> exam scripts.

I think "answer papers" is probably the most generally useful. So I would say "Request safe-keeping of (exam) answer papers".

You might or might not need "exam" in there depending on whether the context of an exam is already established.

You could say "exam papers", but that is subject to the ambiguity AdrianHHH pointed out: it could also mean the papers that were to be presented to the candidates in the exam.